# Dynamically create column in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have Create a table within My procedure.
I have start date and end date value. I want create columns with this date range like if start date is 15 july 2013 and end date is 18 july 2013 then there are 4 columns(july1,july2,july3,july4) are created.

How can I achieve this. I have used sql server 2008..
please help me.....

Sir from front end i have fromdate and Todate fields then on submit I have called a Sp from my C# code, Now I want to create a table within my Proc. table must have no. of columns as with no. of days exists between given dates.

Comment: Please reformulate your question. From what I can understand, you have two columns which represent a date range, and depending on the number of days between those two dates, you want that number of columns ADDED to your table or CREATED in another table? (this may be totally wrong, but it's what understand from your question)

Comment: What u have tried in SP? First show the effort.

Comment: Sir from front end i have fromdate and Todate fields then on submit I have called a Sp from my C# code, Now I want to create a table within my Proc. table must have no. of columns as  with no. of days exists between given dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @dtmin date
DECLARE @dtmax date
DECLARE @dynsql nvarchar(3000)
DECLARE @colname varchar(20)
SET @dynsql = N'CREATE TABLE trial('
SET @dtmin = {d '2013-07-15'}
SET @dtmax = {d '2013-07-18'}
DECLARE @currdate date
SET @currdate = @dtmin

WHILE (@currdate <= @dtmax)
BEGIN
    SET @colname = DATENAME(month, @currdate) + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(day, @currdate))

    SET @dynsql = @dynsql + @colname + ' varchar(10)'

    IF (@currdate < @dtmax)
    BEGIN
        SET @dynsql = @dynsql + ', '
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @dynsql = @dynsql + ')'
    END

    SET @currdate = DATEADD(day, 1, @currdate)
END

EXEC sp_executesql @dynsql
```

P.S.: I don't know the reason of your request, but generally is not correct create table in this way because the information you want to put into columns, should be put in the rows.

Example:
If I want to store sales day by day, the correct table, I named SALES, is:
SALES (id varchar(36), dt datetime, amount decimal(19,2))
instead of
SALES (ID VARCHAR(36), dt1 decimal(19,2), dt2 decimal(19,2)... and so on)

Because if you want to change your period you must rewrite your table, if you want query your table you must write several queries for each situation. It's very hard work on this table.

Please, reconsider you choice.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You may have accepted the answer above, but even wanting to do this goes well against the principles behind relational databases.  I'd seriously consider what you're trying to do and your approach.

Comment: You're right, but we don't know the reason of this request. It's very hard work on that table, but I focalized my answer on implementing the solution.

Comment: Yes I know and I am sure the OP appreciates your answer but I think it's also important that they know they're probably heading in the wrong direction.

Comment: Hi, I've integrated my answer with a little example about the correct creation of table. I hope our friend reconsider his choice. Have a nice day.

Comment: Yeah this question falls in the category where the answer is "please don't, and here is how you do it".

Comment: Hi all thannks for showing interests , actually I just want to display data from some source who produced record in order as i created my table column so I just created column in this manner and finally I drop the table